# Bit placement puzzle

Tags: puzzle

Consider a binary vector of length $n$ that is initially all zeros.  You choose a bit of the vector and set it to $1$. Now a process starts that sets the bit that is the greatest distance from any $1$ bit to $1$ (or an arbitrary choice of furthest bit if there is more than one). This happens repeatedly with the rule that no two $1$ bits can be next to each other. It terminates when there is no more space to place a $1$ bit. The goal is to place the initial $1$ bit so that as many bits as possible are set to $1$ on termination.

Say $n =2$. Then wherever we set the bit we end up with exactly one bit set.

For $n =3$, if we set the first bit we get $101$ in the end. But if we set the middle bit we get $010$ which is not optimal.

For $n=4$, whichever bit we set we end up with two set.

For $n=5$, setting the first gives us $10101$ with three bits set in the end.

For $n=7$, we need to set the third bit to get $1010101$ it seems.

What is the simplest rule for placing the initial bit which will always give an optimal answer?

Comment: Otherwise known as "the urinal problem".

Comment: See section 3.3 of [this](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~kranakis/Papers/urinal.pdf) paper.

Comment: The density of bits placed can be anywhere from $1/3$ to $1/2$.  If your first placement leaves $2^k$ empty bits on one side, then those bits will be filled optimally.  So a reasonable approach is to place your first bit at position $2^k+1$, where $k$ is as large as possible; you're guaranteed to fill at least $5/12$ of the bits that way.

Comment: I have checked this conjecture numerically for $n\le 10000$; thus far it always holds.  There are many cases where the best position is unique.

Comment: The process doesn't seem well-defined. In $00100$, which bit will get set next? In that case it doesn't actually matter, but how can we be sure it will never matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First consider the number of bits that will be turned on by this process in a string of $n$ zeroes flanked by ones.  Call that number $A_n$.  Clearly $A_1=A_2=0$, and for $n\ge 3$ the following recursion holds:
$$
A_n = 1+A_{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor}+A_{\lceil (n-1)/2 \rceil},
$$
or $$\begin{eqnarray}A_{2k+1}&=&1+2A_{k} \\ A_{2k+2}&=&1+A_{k}+A_{k+1}\end{eqnarray}$$
for $k\ge 1$.
Now consider $B_n$, the number of bits that will be turned on in a string of $n$ zeroes with a single flanking one.  Here $B_{n}=1+A_{n-1}$ for $n\ge 2$, so we find the following:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
B_{2k+2}&=&1+A_{2k+1}&=&2+2A_{k}&=&2B_{k+1} \\
B_{2k+3}&=&1+A_{2k+2}&=&2+A_{k}+A_{k+1}&=&B_{k+1}+B_{k+2}\end{eqnarray}$$
for $k\ge 1$.  (The sequence starts with $B_{0}=B_{1}=0$ and $B_{2}=B_{3}=1$.)
The original problem asks for $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $B_{i-1}+B_{n-i}$ is maximized.  Studying the sequence $B_n$, one sees efficient packing ($B_n=n/2$) when $n$ is a power of $2$, and inefficient packing ($B_n=n/3$) when $n$ is three times a power of $2$.  A reasonable "greedy" conjecture, then, is that forcing the largest possible string of bits into an efficient packing structure, by choosing $$i=2^{\lfloor \log_2(n-1)\rfloor}+1,$$will produce an efficient overall packing; at any rate, it guarantees a packing fraction of $5/12$, since no more than half of the bits are suboptimally packed.

This conjecture seems to hold up numerically; at least for $n\le 10000$, an optimal packing is produced by this choice of $i$.  This choice would seem risky when $n=2^k+3\cdot 2^{k-2}+1$, since the leftover portion is large and its packing is as poor as possible.  Indeed, such values of $n$ have an unusually large number of equally good choices for $i$ (unlike, say, $n=2^k+2^{k-2}+1$); but the simple choice above is always tied for first.

---

A closed-form expression for the number of bits that will be set for a given $(i, n)$ is provided by section 3.3 of [this paper](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~kranakis/Papers/urinal.pdf) on the "urinal problem" (which is essentially what this puzzle is).  In terms of the auxiliary function $$K_n=2^{\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor},$$
which is the largest power of $2$ not greater than $n$, they give the following correct expression for my $B_n$:
$$
B_{n} = \frac{1}{2}K_n + \left(\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{K_n}\right\rfloor - 2\right)\cdot\left(n - \frac{3}{2}K_n\right).
$$
The expression $\lfloor{2n / K_n}\rfloor - 2$ is either equal to $1$ (if $n$'s binary representation starts with $11$) or $0$ (if it starts with $10$), and so $B_{n}$ itself is either $n - K_n$ or $K_n / 2$.  If $n$ is a power of $2$, then clearly $B_{n}=K_n/2=n/2$ exactly.

Now, when the initial bit is placed in the $i$-th position, the total number of bits that will be turned on is $1 + B_{i-1} + B_{n-i}$.
My conjecture is that setting $i=K_{n-1}+1$ will always produce an optimal packing; the number of bits that will be set is then
$$
1 + B_{K_{n-1}} + B_{n-1-K_{n-1}}.
$$
Because $K_{n-1}$ is a power of $2$, this can also be written as
$$
1 + \frac{1}{2}K_{n-1} + B_{n-1-K_{n-1}}.
$$

Comment: If you set $n=3$, then the formula gives you $i=2^1+1=3$, which is correct.

Comment: What is the status of this? Is the conjectured placement location now proved to be optimal?

Comment: No, it's not proven.  But the number of bits that will be set (if the first bit is at the conjectured location) is given in closed form by the final expression.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(k)$, $B(k)$, $C(k)$ be the number of moves if the game starts with $\underbrace{0\ldots0}_k$, $1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_k$, or $1\underbrace{0\ldots0}_k1$, respectively (with $k\ge1$ for the $C$ case so that we start in a legal position).
Clearly $A(0)=0$, $A(1)=1$, $B(0)=B(1)=0$ and also $C(1)=C(2)=0$.
For larger values of $n$ we have the recursions
$$ \begin{align}A(n)&=1+\max_{0\le k< n}(B(k)+B(n-k-1))\\
B(n)&=1+C(n-1)\\
C(2n+1)&=1+2C(n)\\
C(2n)&=1+C(n)+C(n-1)\\
\end{align}$$
So first we should find $C(n)$. By numerical experiments, $C(n)$ seems to grow one by one except that values of form $2^k-1$ are repeated $2^{k}+1$ times. We can cast this more precisely into the following

**Lemma.**
$$\tag1 C(n) =\begin{cases}0&\text{if }n\in\{1,2\},\\
 \min\{n-2^{k+1},2^{k+1}-1\}&\text{if }k=\lfloor\log_2\tfrac n3\rfloor \text{ (i.e. }3\cdot 2^k\le n<3\cdot2^{k+1}\text{)}.\end{cases}$$
We can see this by induction: For $n\in\{1,2,3\}$ we check (1) immediately. For even $n=2m>3$ with $3\cdot 2^k<n<3\cdot 2^{k+1}$  we have 
$$\begin{align}C(n)&=1+C(m)+C(m-1)\\&= 1+\min\{m-2^{k},2^{k}-1\}+\min\{m-1-2^{k},2^{k}-1\}\\&=\begin{cases}1+m-2^{k}+m-1-2^{k}&\text{if }m-2^{k}\le 2^{k}-1\\
1+2^{k}-1+2^{k}-1&\text{if }m-2^{k}\ge2^{k}\end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}n-2^{k+1}&\text{if }n-2^{k+1}\le 2^{k+1}-2\\
2^{k+1}-1&\text{if }n-2^{k+1}\ge2^{k+1}\end{cases}\end{align}$$
(note that $n-2^{k+1}=2^{k+1}-1$ can't happen) and if $n=3\cdot 2^k$ with $k\ge1$ we have
$$\begin{align}C(n)&=1+C(m)+C(m-1) \\
&= 1+\min\{3\cdot 2^{k-1}-2^{k},2^{k}-1\}+\min\{3\cdot 2^{k-1}-1-2^{k},2^{k}-1\}\\
&=1+2^{k-1}+2^{k-1}-1=2^{k}=n-2^{k+1}\end{align}$$
as needed.
And for odd $n=2m+1$ with $3\cdot2^k\le n<3\cdot2^{k+1}$ we have $3\cdot2^{k-1}\le m<3\cdot 2^k$ and hence
$$C(n)=1+2C(m)=1+2\min\{m-2^{k},2^{k}-1\}=\min\{1+2(m-2^{k}),1+2(2^{k}-1)\}=\min\{n-2^{k+1},2^{k+1}-1\}$$
also in this case. $_\square$

Now we immediately obtain

**Corollary.**
$$B(n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }n\in\{0,1\},\\
1&\text{if }n\in\{2,3\},\\
\min\{n-2^{k+1},2^{k+1}\}& \text{with }k=\lfloor\log_2\tfrac {n-1}3\rfloor\text{ if }n>3.\end{cases}$$
If $n>1$ then $\frac n3\le B(n)\le \frac n2$ with equality on the left iff $n$ is three times a power of two and equality on the right iff $n$ is a power of two.

*Proof:*
The formula for $B$ follows immediately from the lemma and $B(n)=1+C(n-1)$.
For $n>3$ note that $k=\lfloor\log_2\tfrac {n-1}3\rfloor$ implies $3\cdot 2^k\le n-1<3\cdot 2^{k+1}$, i.e. $n=3\cdot 2^k+r$ with $1\le r\le 3\cdot 2^k$.
Next $B(n)=n-2^{k+1} = 2^k+r$ if $r\le 2^k$ and then $\frac{n}{B(n)}=\frac{3\cdot 2^k+r}{2^k+r}$ is between $\frac{4\cdot 2^k}{2\cdot2^k}=2$ and $\frac{3\cdot 2^k}{2^k}=3$. And $B(n)=2^{k+1}$ if $2^k\le r\le 3\cdot 2^k$ and then $\frac{n}{B(n)}=\frac{3\cdot 2^k+r}{2\cdot 2^k}$ is between $\frac{3+1}{2}=2$ and $\frac{3+3}{2}=3$. This shows the inequality for $n>3$, the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ can be checked manually. We also see from the argument that $\frac{n}{B(n)}=2$ and $\frac{n}{B(n)}=3$ occur only for $r=2^k$ and $r=3\cdot 2^k$, respectively. $_\square$

The most important aspect of the corollary is: $B(n+1)-B(n)$ is either $0$ or $1$. Therefore, when determining $a, b$ such that $a+b=n-1$ and $A(n)=1+B(a)+B(b)$ we observe that we may replace $a$ with $a+1$ (and $b$ with $b-1$) if $3\cdot 2^k\le a<4\cdot 2^k$ (and $a<n-1$) as that leaves $B(a)$ unchanged and hence cannot decrease the value of $B(a)+B(b)$. On the other hand, if $4\cdot 2^k<a\le 6\cdot 2^k$, then decreasing $a$ increases $B(a)$ and hence cannot decrease the value of $B(a)+B(b)$. If we start with an otimal pair $(a,b)$ with $a\ge b$, this procedure leads to another optimal pair where $a$ has become a power of two, $a=4\cdot 2^k$. In this process, $a$ may have become $<b$ or remained $\ge b$.
In the second case when $a\ge b$, we have that $a$ is the largest power of two $\le n-1$.
In the first case, the initial $a\ge b$ was $<6\cdot 2^k$, which means that $8\cdot 2^k<n-1<12\cdot 2^k$, so $4\cdot 2^k<b<8\cdot 2^k$. If $4\cdot 2^k<b\le 6\cdot 2^k$, we obtain $B(a)+B(b) = 2^{k+2}=B(8\cdot 2^k)\le B(8\cdot 2^k)+B(n-1-8\cdot 2^k)$ and by maximality $B(n-1-8\cdot 2^k)=0$, i.e. $n$ is slightly above a power of two and we may as well pick $a=8\cdot 2^k$. If on the other hand $6\cdot 2^k<b<8\cdot 2^k$, we may swap $a$ and $b$ and repeat the above procedure, this time at most increasing $a$ so that we end up in the second case again.
In summary, we may assume wlog. that $a$ is the largest power of two $\le n-1$ and thus have proved

**Theorem.** For $n=2^k+r+1$ with $0\le r<2^k$, we have
$$  A(n)=1+B(2^k)+B(r)=1+2^{k-1}+B(r). _\square$$

If $r>1$ in the theorem and we write it as  $c\cdot 2^m$ with $3\le c<6$, then $B(r)=(c-2)2^m$ if $3\le c\le 4$ and $B(r)=2\cdot 2^m$ if $4\le c<6$.
From $2^k>r$ we have $m\le k-2$ in the first case and $m\le k-3$ in the second case.
So in the first case we find $$\frac{n-1}{A(n)-1}=\frac{2^k+c2^m}{2^{k-1}+(c-2)2^m}\le\frac{2^k+3\cdot 2^{m}}{2^{k-1}+2^{m}}\le \frac{2^k+3\cdot2^{k-2}}{2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}}=\frac 73.$$
And in the second case we find 
$$ \frac{n-1}{A(n)-1}=\frac{2^k+c2^m}{2^{k-1}+2^{m+1}}\le \frac{2^k+6\cdot 2^m}{2^{k-1}+2\cdot 2^{m}}\le\frac{2^k+3\cdot 2^{k-2}}{2^{k-1}+2^{k-2}}=\frac{7}{3}$$
as well (a slight improvement over a more straightforward estimate giving $\frac{n}{A(n)}\le \frac{12}5$).